# Can quantum particles really communicate in the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, causality

The quantum entanglement and delayed choice quantum eraser variation to the double slit experiment has given very strange results. So if a particle is detected then the pattern is changed. Does the detected particle communicate with its entangled pair in the past? or there is another explanation to it?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand this is to recognise that the wave function does not describe the physical state of the particle, but rather it describes the information we have about the particle. When a particle is detected, it gives us information about that particle in the past, and consequently it also gives us information about the entangled pair of that particle in the past.